# Selectize Ajax Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, selectize.js

The selectize dropdown I have on the page gets populated from an AJAX call via the following.  What's not working is I need to run some additional code right after the `callback()` method invocation, but it never continues into the rest of the callback.  For instance, the following in the success callback doesn't run the additional code identified:

```
var $ddl = $("#ContactID");
var control = $ddl[0].selectize;

control.load(function () {
   $.ajax({
      url: "validURL",
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
         id: recordID
      },
      error: function () {
         alert("Error retrieving data");
         callback();
      },
      success: function (result) { 
         callback(result.data);   
         //Does not get called below
         loadAdditionalInformation(recordID);
      }
   });
});
```

However, if I do this, it works:

```
success: function (result) {
         window.setTimeout(function() { 
            callback(result.data);   
         }, 0);

         loadAdditionalInformation(recordID);
}
```

I need to call a method at the point the list is loaded, so I am not sure I want to continue with that, so why is the success callback aborting after the `callback()` method call.

Comment: it does not make sense. timeout 0 does inner function asynchronous so only explanation is error/infinite loop during callback function.. It is dumb question, but did you check console?

Comment: @bigless It's a perfectly fine question and Zamrony was right, I forgot a parameter, so I was dealing with undefined, but it was swallowed for some reason, don't know why.  Again, I wasn't suggesting `setTimeout` as an answer, but something I noticed and tried....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load` expects two parameters, `query` and `callback`.

```
 $('#ContactID').selectize({
      ....
      load : function (query, callback) {
         $.ajax({
             ....
             success : function(res) {
                   callback(res.data);
                   doOtherThings(res);
             }
         });
      }
 });
```

Your code does not pass any of those parameters, so it is very likely that when `success()` is called, the `callback()` function is undefined.
I suggest put breakpoint and inspect it.